# Why does the linker modify a --defsym "absolute address"

Tags: linux, linker, shared

Goal: a shared library to use a function from an executable (which does not export symbols).

Means: `gcc -Wl,--defsym,function=0x432238`

The man page states that:

```
"--defsym symbol=expression" Create a global symbol in the output
file, containing the absolute address given by expression.
```

To my dismay, `dlopen()` is adding `0x7ffff676f000`, the shared library's base address (this is 64-bit code) to the exported "absolute symbol address":

```
        executable        shared library
        ---------- linker --------------
symbol: 0x432238   =====> 0x7ffff6ba1238
```

objdump shows the correct symbol address (`0x432238`) in the library, but once loaded with `dlopen()`, the symbol has address `0x7ffff6ba1238`.

If, once loaded, I manually patch the library symbol to the correct address then all works fine (else, the library SEGFAULTs).

- Why the "absolute address" is modified?
- How to avoid it?

**Update:**

*I contest the technical relevance of the reply below, and, even more its 'update':*

Having --defsym to define a relocated symbol in a PIC library/executable is pointless (it does not serve ANY purpose other than polluting the binary without any usable feature).

Therefore, the only relevant use of --defsym in a PIC shared library or PIC executable should be to define a (*non-relocated*) "absolute address".

Incidentally, that's the official purpose of --defsym if you bother to read the man page:

*"Create a global symbol in the output file, containing the `absolute address` given by expression."*

At best, this is a Linux linker deffect which would be trivial to fix. And for those who can't wait for the people-in-denial to realize (and fix) their mistake, the solution is to patch the relocation table after the binary image has been loaded by the defective linker.

Then, --defsym becomes useful in PIC libraries/executables, which seems to me is a welcome progress.

Comment: `--defsym` is very useful as implemented, and your claims that current behavior is useless or a bug are difficult to comprehend. For example, in Intel SGX a `--defsym __ImageBase=0` is used so that code running in an enclave can find the address at which an enclave is loaded. This allows to take stacktraces, compute offset from `__ImageBase`, and symbolicate outside the enclave. This is just one example. Changing the behavior as you suggest "patch the relocation table after the binary image has been loaded" would break countless projects.

Comment: https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/linux-2.2/docs/Intel_SGX_Developer_Reference_Linux_2.2_Open_Source.pdf

Comment: @Chris Beck, I am amazed by the submissive, sterile "compliance" of the replies and the lack of their ability to address the technical question to bring a solution. Also, I am stunned to see that nobody seems to realize how the current (dysfunctional) behavior has possibly been purposely chosen to generate endless security issues.

Answer (score 9):

You appear to have fundamentally misunderstood what `--defsym` does.

```
--defsym=symbol=expression
   Create a global symbol in the *output* file, ...
```

That is, you are creating the new symbol *in the library* that you are building. As such, the symbol is (naturally) relocated with the library.

I am guessing you want something like this instead:

```
// code in library
int fn()
{
    // exe_fn not exported from the executable, but we know where it is.
    int (*exe_fn)(void) = (int (*)(void)) 0x432238;
    return (*exe_fn)();
}
```

If you didn't want to hard-code `0x432238` into the library, and instead pass the value on command line at build time, just use a `-DEXE_FN=0x432238` to achieve that.

**Update:**

> Goal: a shared library to use a function from an executable

That goal **can not** be achieved by the method you selected. You'll have to use other means.

> Why the "absolute address" is modified?

It isn't. When you ask the linker to define `function` at absolute address `0x432238`, it does **exactly** that. You can see it in `objdump`, `nm` and `readelf -s` output.

But because the symbol is defined *in* the shared library, all *references* to that symbol are relocated, i.e. adjusted by the shared library load address (that is done by the dynamic loader). It makes *no sense whatsoever* for the dynamic loader to do otherwise.

> How to avoid it?

You can't. Use other means to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does not resolve my problem because a define will NOT be defined as a *symbol* in the shared library. How do I actually create a SYMBOL that GDB will be able to list?

Comment: I know how to make ugly hacks that will work, but is there any 'clean' way to do it? That was my question.

Comment: Regarding the 'man' page, what the "containing the absolute address given by expression" means?

Comment: "define will NOT be defined as a symbol in the shared library". You *don't* want a defined symbol in the shared library. You want one in the executable. Since you can't (or don't want to) rebuild the executable so it exports the symbol, you are then left with hacks.

Comment: I do *really want* a symbol in the shared library, and there are various ways to make this work as expected, ranging from simple wrappers to patching what the linker manual insists to call an "absolute address" before relocating it. Thanks anyway for your reply, which might help others.

Comment: "I do really want a symbol in the shared library". No, you don't. Your question asks "... use a function from an executable". Make up your mind: if the function code is in the main executable, then it is *not*  (and should not be defined) in the shared library.

Comment: Flatly ignoring my expressed constraints will not give you any point. I said that I wanted a symbol in the library for debugging / tracing since the executable will not export any symbol. Also, let me judge of what I want or not. I would rather appreciate to see you reply to my questions (left unaddressed).

Answer (score 2):

Adding a counterpoint: yes there is an actual use to this but I think it's indeed broken, not only with dynamic libraries but also with position-independent executables.

`ld` itself will use symbols when used to embed binary files into executables:

`ld -r -b binary hello_world.txt -o hello_world.o`

this will produce an object file with, among others, the following symbols:

```
000000000000000c g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_hello_world_txt_end
000000000000000c g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 _binary_hello_world_txt_size
0000000000000000 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary_hello_world_txt_start
```

so that an executable that is include them can just use `extern` variables to access them. (... as in: our "hello world" text from hello_world.txt is the only thing in the `.data` section, with length `0xc`).

Linking this object file into an executable file (and not stripping symbols) results in

```
0000000000411040 g     .data  0000000000000000              _binary_hello_world_txt_start
000000000041104c g     .data  0000000000000000              _binary_hello_world_txt_end
000000000000000c g     *ABS*  0000000000000000              _binary_hello_world_txt_size
```

and we can do things like

```
extern char _binary_hello_world_txt_start;
extern char _binary_hello_world_txt_size; // "char" is just made up in this one

// (...)
printf("text: %s\n", &_binary_hello_world_txt_start);
printf("number of bytes in it: %d\n", (int) (&_binary_hello_world_txt_size));
```

(yes it's looks fairly weird that we're looking for an address of something (which symbols are usually used for), and then we're treating it as an integer... but it actually works.)

Note also how the linker does know what it should relocate and what it shouldn't; the data pointers are relative to `.data`, while the size is `*ABS*`, which, as Gil describes, is not supposed to be relocated (... since it isn't calculated relatively to anything).

However, this only works *in non-position-independent executables*. Once you go from `-fPIE` (which is gcc's default lately in modern Linux distros, as it looks like) to `-no-pie`, the dynamic linker relocates everything, including `*ABS*` symbols. This is happening at runtime link time: the symbol tables look the same, regardless of how the executable was compiled.

The fact that the same thing happens for shared libraries seems to be a consequence of the same thing: the relocation of dynamically placed binaries (either a position-independent executable or a shared library) results in similar relocations, which do make sense for functions included in the binary itself, but not for `*ABS*` data.

Sadly, I don't have an answer to either of the questions: I also think it's done incorrectly, and I do not know how to fix it (see [Getting the value of *ABS* symbols from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57018109/getting-the-value-of-abs-symbols-from-c) for another issue bumping into the same problem).

However, given how even GNU ld itself chooses to embed a size as a symbol this way... I do think this application / question is entirely valid, so as for answer:

- ... it's done because the implementation isn't actually correct
- as a workaround, "generating a header file with absolute addresses inline" comes to mind, following Employed Russian's answer

... but I'd actually be interested in how exactly to patch the relocation table the way Gil mentioned in the question!

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of --defsym changed between gcc 5.4.0 (using Ubuntu 16.04.4) and 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 18.04). At 5.40, --defsym created a symbol representing an absolute, non-relocatable address. At 7.3.0, readelf -s shows the symbol as "ABS", but the symbol is in fact relocated when the program executes. (This has caused problems for my application, too.)

An absolute address might represent something like a memory-mapped device register or an interrupt vector, something that stays in one place irrespective of where the application is loaded. The older behavior is correct - absolute addresses must not be relocated. If the relocation happens when the executable image is loaded into memory, it might not be a gcc problem, but it is a problem.