# Resolving statically defined symbols in a shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-memory, static-linking, shared-objects

I have a legacy system which declares symbols in a shared memory region. The addresses of the are statically defined to absolute addresses in memory using gcc's linker command script function. I can build a static test executable in C which references these symbols correctly when I pass the static object file and linker command script during compilation, and attach to the shared memory region (`shmat()`, etc).

What I am trying to do is build a Python extension library which can access the same symbols. Being able to access the library from Python requires the `-shared` and `-fPIC` options from what I understand. When I compile this way, the symbols are no longer located at the correct addresses. Compiling the C test program with `-shared -fPIC` causes the addresses to be wrong as well.
I can define the symbols within the extension library directly:

```
int *pA = 0x030A0000;
```

and this works when compiled using `-shared -fPIC`. But should I? There are hundreds of symbols I need and it would be unmaintainable if the addresses ever changed. It seems like there should be a way to indicate to the linker that these symbols should not be relocated, but nothing I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253801/how-to-force-symbols-from-a-static-library-to-be-included-in-a-shared-library-bu) has [worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054942/gcc-rdynamic-not-working-with-static-libraries), including compiling as below:

In the code for Python extension:

```
extern int symbol_i_need;
...
printf("%d", symbol_i_need); // Seg fault
```

Compile commands:

```
gcc -fPIC -o my_module.o my_module.c /path/static_object.o /path/linker_command_script.ld 
gcc -shared -fPIC -o my_module.so my_module.o -Wl,-Bstatic,/path/static_defined_object.o,/path/linker_command_script.ld,-Bdynamic -rdynamic
```

Comment: `PIC` stands for 'Position Independent Code' and indicates to the linker that it can take the function from the library and place it anywhere in the code section of memory.  I may not be as swift as many others but other than what you're doing I don't really have a solution.

Comment: Yes, I read the description for the flag in the man page and it raised some warning flags with me. However, I am using the distutils to build the Python module and the flag is inserted automatically. My assumption was that it was required for the module to work with Python correctly but I will do some investigating.

Answer (score 0):

After researching and much experimentation with various flags (`--just-symbols`, `-Bsymbolic`, `--dynamic-list`, `--defsym`, etc) and with the help of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032598/gnu-ld-how-to-override-a-symbol-value-an-address-defined-by-the-linker-script) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368423/why-does-the-linker-modify-a-defsym-absolute-address) and objdump and some printf's, I found that the way shared objects index their symbols prevent the result I was going for. It's really not feasible to compile the desired Python extension as a shared object without manually setting up pointers to all the symbols you need.

What I was able to do was add the same module code I had written to the built-in Python modules. Recompiling Python with my custom module there and linking against the static object file and linker command scripts I already had (added to the Modules/Setup file: `my_module my_module.c -I/include/path -Xlinker /path/static_object.o /path/linker_script.ld`) allowed all the symbols to resolve to their correct addresses. The documentation within the Python source was sufficient to show me how to do this.