# Getting the value of *ABS* symbols from C

Tags: c, ld

What is the proper way of accessing the actual value of an `*ABS*` (absolute, not-to-be-relocated) symbol from C?

I'm using ld to embed data (... a HTML template) in an executable (... following the method described in https://csl.name/post/embedding-binary-data/). As in:

`ld -r -b binary [the_file_to_be_embedded] -o [some_object.o]`

Then, I'm using

```
const char _some_object_start;
const char _some_object_end;
const int _some_object_size;
```

in the actual code. The actual linked text works nicely by getting char pointers with `&_some_object_start`; reading the size keeps breaking in interesting, platform-dependent ways though: on ARM64, `(long) &_some_object_size` actually ends up being the size, but on x64 the compiler is trying to make it PC-relative and doesn't end up with the right thing.

For reference, this is how the actual symbol table looks like:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
0000000d g       .data  00000000 _binary_hello_world_txt_end
0000000d g       *ABS*  00000000 _binary_hello_world_txt_size
00000000 g       .data  00000000 _binary_hello_world_txt_start
```

(obtained by objdump -x.)

I presume `ld` adds size data assuming that there is some reasonable way for code linked with it to read it, therefore the question.

(... which is more on the theoretical side, as `&_obj_end - &obj_start` does still resolve to the actual data length; I'm curious specifically about `_obj_size` though.)

Comment: You can get the size as by casting addresses of end and start to uintptr_t and taking the difference

Answer (score 1):

The value of a symbol is its address, so `&symbol_name` should retrieve it.

example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern char abs_sym;
int main() { printf("%p\n", (void*)&abs_sym); }
```

run example:

```
$ gcc ldabs.c  -no-pie -Wl,--defsym=abs_sym=0xab && ./a.out
  0xab
```

Comment: Why cast the address to `long` instead of `void *` and use the `"%p"` format to print it? There's no guarantee that `long` is the same size as a pointer, not even on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude %p prints in hexadecimal  and I wanted decimal and when you're comparing compiler/linker behavior on x86-64 you're already in implementation-defined area anyway, but sure `"%p", (void*)x` is of course the most proper way to print a pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Point taken, though. I'm setting and printing (%p) hex values now.

Comment: yeaaah, the gcc x86_64 issue is what I bumped into, too. Sadly, one of the target platforms is just that... it's interesting though how it's working on clang! do you think it's a gcc bug, or is it just unspecified?

Comment: @Latanius Found the cause of the problem. The gcc was passing `-pie` to the linker, which causes the absolute symbol to be handled incorrectly. Passing `-no-pie` solves the problem. (My clang doesn't do that so clang works with absolute symbols by default.)

Comment: nice, thanks!!! Yeah, this indeed seems to be the solution. (... actually, it'd be nice if it also worked with -fPIE since technically it's a different sort of symbol... the linux linker disagrees apparently.)
(... also, would you mind adding an update to the answer to point out that "position independence" is the key? it feels like it's easy to miss if it's only in the comments :) Thanks!)